# How to run a webserver module in my distributed project?

Tags: python

I have a WebSocket python file named `ipmi_management_webserver.py`, you see the bellow:

```
# coding: utf-8
import socket
import struct
import hashlib, base64
import threading
import time

connectionlist = {}   
g_code_length = 0
g_header_length = 0   
PRINT_FLAG = True

def get_datalength(msg):
    global g_code_length
    global g_header_length
    g_code_length = msg[1] & 127
    if g_code_length == 126:
        g_code_length = struct.unpack('>H', msg[2:4])[0]
        g_header_length = 8
    elif g_code_length == 127:
        g_code_length = struct.unpack('>Q', msg[2:10])[0]
        g_header_length = 14
    else:
        g_header_length = 6
    g_code_length = int(g_code_length)
    return g_code_length



def parse_data(msg):
    global g_code_length
    g_code_length = msg[1] & 127
    if g_code_length == 126:
        g_code_length = struct.unpack('>H', msg[2:4])[0]
        masks = msg[4:8]
        data = msg[8:]
    elif g_code_length == 127:
        g_code_length = struct.unpack('>Q', msg[2:10])[0]
        masks = msg[10:14]
        data = msg[14:]
    else:
        masks = msg[2:6]
        data = msg[6:]
    en_bytes = b""
    cn_bytes = []
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        nv = chr(d ^ masks[i % 4])
        nv_bytes = nv.encode()
        nv_len = len(nv_bytes)
        if nv_len == 1:
            en_bytes += nv_bytes
        else:
            en_bytes += b'%s'
            cn_bytes.append(ord(nv_bytes.decode()))
    if len(cn_bytes) > 2:
        cn_str = ""
        clen = len(cn_bytes)
        count = int(clen / 3)
        for x in range(count):
            i = x * 3
            b = bytes([cn_bytes[i], cn_bytes[i + 1], cn_bytes[i + 2]])
            cn_str += b.decode()
        new = en_bytes.replace(b'%s%s%s', b'%s')
        new = new.decode()
        res = (new % tuple(list(cn_str)))
    else:
        res = en_bytes.decode()
    return res


def sendMessage(msg):
    global connectionlist
    send_msg = b""   
    send_msg += b"\x81"
    back_str = []
    back_str.append('\x81')
    data_length = len(msg.encode())  
    if PRINT_FLAG:
        print("INFO: send message is %s and len is %d" % (msg, len(msg.encode('utf-8'))))

    if data_length <= 125:  
        send_msg += str.encode(chr(data_length))
    elif data_length <= 65535:  
        send_msg += struct.pack('b', 126)
        send_msg += struct.pack('>h', data_length)
    elif data_length <= (2 ^ 64 - 1):  
        send_msg += struct.pack('b', 127)
        send_msg += struct.pack('>q', data_length)
    else:
        print(u'too long')
    send_message = send_msg + msg.encode('utf-8')

    for connection in connectionlist.values():
        if send_message != None and len(send_message) > 0:
            connection.send(send_message)



def deleteconnection(item):
    global connectionlist
    del connectionlist['connection' + item]



class WebSocket(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, index, name, remote, path=""):
        # thread
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.conn = conn
        self.index = index
        self.name = name
        self.remote = remote
        self.path = path
        self.GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
        self.buffer = ""
        self.buffer_utf8 = b""
        self.length_buffer = 0

    def generate_token(self, WebSocketKey):
        WebSocketKey = WebSocketKey + self.GUID
        Ser_WebSocketKey = hashlib.sha1(WebSocketKey.encode(encoding='utf-8')).digest()
        WebSocketToken = base64.b64encode(Ser_WebSocketKey) 
        return WebSocketToken.decode('utf-8')


    def run(self):

        if PRINT_FLAG:
            print('Socket %s Start!' % self.index)
        global g_code_length
        global g_header_length
        self.handshaken = False   
        while True:
            if self.handshaken == False:  
                if PRINT_FLAG:
                    print('INFO: Socket %s Start Handshaken with %s!' % (self.index, self.remote))
                self.buffer = self.conn.recv(1024).decode(
                    'utf-8')  
                if PRINT_FLAG:
                    print("INFO: Socket %s self.buffer is {%s}" % (self.index, self.buffer))
                if self.buffer.find('\r\n\r\n') != -1:
                    headers = {}
                    header, data = self.buffer.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)  

                    for line in header.split("\r\n")[1:]:  
                        key, value = line.split(": ", 1)  
                        headers[key] = value
                    try:
                        WebSocketKey = headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"]
                    except KeyError:
                        print("Socket %s Handshaken Failed!" % (self.index))
                        deleteconnection(str(self.index))
                        self.conn.close()
                        break
                    WebSocketToken = self.generate_token(WebSocketKey)
                    headers["Location"] = ("ws://%s%s" % (headers["Host"], self.path))

                    handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" \
                                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" \
                                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + WebSocketToken + "\r\n" \
                                                                            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n"
                    self.conn.send(handshake.encode(encoding='utf-8'))  

                    self.handshaken = True  
                    sendMessage("Welocomg " + self.name + " !")
                    g_code_length = 0
                else:
                    print("Socket %s Error2!" % (self.index))
                    deleteconnection(str(self.index))
                    self.conn.close()
                    break
            else:

                mm = self.conn.recv(128)

                if g_code_length == 0:
                    get_datalength(mm)  
                self.length_buffer += len(mm)
                self.buffer_utf8 += mm
                if self.length_buffer - g_header_length < g_code_length:
                    if PRINT_FLAG:
                        print("INFO: finish")
                    continue
                else:
                    if PRINT_FLAG:
                        print("g_code_length:", g_code_length)
                        print("INFO Line 204: Recv info %s,len %d:" % (self.buffer_utf8, len(self.buffer_utf8)))

                    if not self.buffer_utf8:
                        continue
                    recv_message = parse_data(self.buffer_utf8)
                    if recv_message == "quit":
                        print("Socket %s Logout!" % (self.index))
                        nowTime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
                        sendMessage("%s %s say: %s" % (nowTime, self.remote, self.name + " Logout"))
                        deleteconnection(str(self.index))
                        self.conn.close()
                        break
                    else:
                        nowTime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
                        sendMessage("%s %s say: %s" % (nowTime, self.remote, recv_message))

                        print('ldl:', recv_message)

                    g_code_length = 0
                    self.length_buffer = 0
                    self.buffer_utf8 = b""


# WebSocket 
class WebSocketServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = None
        self.i = 0

    # begin
    def begin(self):
        if PRINT_FLAG:
            print('WebSocketServer Start!')
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ip = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 65432
        if PRINT_FLAG:
            print("WebServer is listening %s,%d" % (ip, port))
        self.socket.bind((ip, port))
        self.socket.listen(50)

        global connectionlist

        while True:

            connection, address = self.socket.accept()

            newSocket = WebSocket(connection, self.i, address[0], address)

            newSocket.start()

            connectionlist['connection' + str(self.i)] = connection
            self.i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = WebSocketServer()
    server.begin()
```

I use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` the function to create the WebSocketServer, and in my test environment I can run the file directly to initial the server:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = WebSocketServer()
    server.begin()
```

---

But, however, in my Django project, in my distribute environment:

this is my project's `wsgi` python module:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Qiy.settings")

import django

print("django.setup()")
django.setup()

from socketio import Middleware
from xxx.qiy_admin_website_chat.views import sio

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)



import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

I use the command to run my django project:

```
SCREEN -d -m python3 -m Qiy.wsgi
```

now, how can I run my `ipmi_management_webserver.py` in my distributed project?