# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte when I execute the ` b.decode()`

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a code like bellow:

```
cn_bytes = [157, 188, 156]

cn_str = ""
clen = len(cn_bytes)
count = int(clen / 3)
for x in range(count):
    i = x * 3
    b = bytes([cn_bytes[i], cn_bytes[i + 1], cn_bytes[i + 2]])

    print(b)

    cn_str += b.decode()
```

when I execute it, I will get bellow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dele/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/testDemo01/testDemo01/test08.py", line 30, in <module>
    cn_str += b.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte
```

there says:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: I want to get the `cn_str`, but the b.decode() get error now.

Comment: In the truth this is part of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036745/how-to-run-a-webserver-module-in-my-distributed-project),  when I run the websocket server there I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think you can't convert entire list as bytes using `bytes()` . But still You can convert it into bytes by iterate through individual elements.

```
b = [cn_bytes[i], cn_bytes[i + 1], cn_bytes[i + 2]]

cn_str =  [bytes(i)for i in b]
```